# Is there anyway to get a more solid connection from pads to planes in Eagle pcb layout?

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, eaglecad, surface-mount, connect

Below, in blue and white, is the suggested pcb layout from the data sheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/RPX_1_0-1903909.pdf
[image]

and here is my pcb layout from eagle

[image]

as you can see in the data sheet example the blue plane fully encompasses the pads. But in my Eagle PCB layout the red plane is connected to the pads by only a few connections.
Is there any way to make more solid connections?

Comment: I'm not experienced with eagle, but it might help to know that those are called thermal reliefs. The point is to make it so you don't have to heat up an entire ground plane to solder a pad; I don't know if there's any point to them if you're going to be reflowing the board.

Comment: This is refered to as thermal relief in the options, you currently have the cross style thermal relief selected, you want solid . This can be set in the options for the plane/pour.